# LAMP server with remote MySQL on CentOS 6.4

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql, php, lamp

I am pretty new to linux and LAMP setup. I want to setup a LAMP environment with AP on one linux server and M on a different linux server. I have a hard time finding a relevant document with such a configuration.

I have done the following steps so far:

server1:

```
yum install -y httpd
/sbin/service httpd restart
yum install -y php php-mysql
sed -i "s/Listen 80/#Listen 80/g" /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
yum install -y mod_ssl openssl
/sbin/service httpd restart
service iptables stop
```

I changed the ServerName in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf from

```
#ServerName www.example.com:80
```

to

```
ServerName 172.32.35.14 (ip address of server1)
/sbin/service httpd restart
```

server2:

```
yum install -y mysql-libs
yum install -y mysql
yum install -y perl-DBI
yum install -y perl-DBD-MySQL
yum install -y mysql-server
/sbin/chkconfig mysqld on
/sbin/service mysqld start
mysql -u root  -e "CREATE USER 'mysqluser' IDENTIFIED by 'password'" 
mysql -u root  -e "CREATE USER 'mysqluser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED by 'password'"
mysql -u root  -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mysqluser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION"
mysql -u root  -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mysqluser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION"
mysql -u mysqluser -p password -e "CREATE DATABASE mysqldb" 
mysql -u mysqluser -p password mysqldb < /tmp/mysqlinstaller/world.sql
service iptables stop
```

Then I had these post configuration steps:

On server 2, where my mysql is installed, I did the following in /etc/my.cnf under the tag [mysqld]

```
bind-address = 172.32.35.14 (ip of server 1 where apache/php are installed)
service mysqld restart

service mysqld start
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

I am facing these issues...

1. When I run the url http://172.32.35.14 on my browser to check the apache installation, I am not able to get the default apache homepage. Instead it says Problem loading page.
2. When I run - service mysqld restart - on the server where mysql is installed, I get the following error:

   service mysqld start
   MySQL Daemon failed to start.
   Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]

Can you point out what I am missing and guide me please

Comment: First of all, you should always check your error logs, they will already give you a better view of what went wrong. Post the relevant lines here. One thing I can see from a distance is that you're using an IP address when you should be using a hostname. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#servername

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions.

Comment: Apologies.. my bad.. Heights of desperation. Im extremely sorry

Answer (score 1):

`bind-address` is the IP of the MySQL server.

http://172.32.35.14 would load from http/port 80 which you disabled. Use https.

I think I will also vote to move the question to the superuser site, this is not a professional question.

Comment: I tried with https too.. Still the same issue. I enabled the port 80 and tried http... I disabled it and tried https... I enabled 443 and tried https.. I tried all permutations

Comment: enabled the port 80 and gave the ServerName 172.32.35.14. I have a sample info.php with the following code <?php phpinfo(); ?> inside. Changed the permissions to 777 and tried to access 172.32.35.14/info.php. But in vain. Problem loading page :(